# Not calling any window-related functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, window

My program doesn't require any windows (it just does file I/O and some computations), and I'm trying to make it as small as possible. I used to have all this at the beginning:

```
WNDCLASS wc;
wc.style = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = NULL;
wc.hCursor = NULL;
wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("");
RegisterClass(&wc);
HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT(""),TEXT(""),0,0,0,0,0,HWND_MESSAGE,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
```

I took it out, so now my program is just WinMain and the useful stuff with no window-related calls. I also de-linked user32.lib. It seems to run fine, but is this bad practice / will it cause any unforeseen problems?

Comment: Don't start with a window program and strip out the window code if you don't want a window in the first place. Make a command-line program instead.

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to start with a "Win32 Console Application", where the Visual Studio wizard will present you by default with a bare-bones application that does nothing at all:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, Windows applications don't *need* to do anything at all. The same applies to a GUI application, if that's really what you need (the basic difference is that a GUI project will not launch in a console window). Though the project wizard inconsistently hands you a scrambled mess of code to start with, you can safely strip out everything. All the way down to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The `stdafx.h` header is a precompiled header that basically does the equivalent of `#include <windows.h>`. But because of how precompiled headers work you must include `stdafx.h` first. That's a different topic altogether, covered extensively on this site already.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you have removed and what you left.If something is left behind then it may cause disturbance in future.

See this simple code to start with Winmain

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(linker,"/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS") 

int _stdcall WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @tenfour:- its an example,an example with some sense.

Answer (score -1):

The minimum requirements of a Win32 Window. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215690/Minimal-WinApi-Window

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

 MSG msg          = {0};
 WNDCLASS wc      = {0}; 
 wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
 wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
 wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
 wc.lpszClassName = L"minwindowsapp";
 if( !RegisterClass(&wc) )
   return 1;

 if( !CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
                   L"Minimal Windows Application",
                   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
                   0,0,640,480,0,0,hInstance,NULL))
    return 2;

    while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 )
        DispatchMessage( &msg );

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

 switch(message)
 {
   case WM_CLOSE:
     PostQuitMessage(0);
     break;
   default:
     return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
 }
 return 0;

}
```

More readings :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis577/lecture/win.htm